# Sending Data over another website via PHP

Tags: php

So I don't even know if that's possible but basically I'd like to create a back office for a client that would handle his sales on two marketplaces (play.com and amazon).

Would I be able to fill forms and send data with PHP? Would I be able to login into websites to scrape date (new orders and such)

I found part of my answer there:
[Creating a 'robot' to fill form with some pages in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270335/creating-a-robot-to-fill-form-with-some-pages-in)

I suspect PHP isn't the language for this, any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Look into PHP's `curl` extension. Alternatively, make your life easier by using a library like [Requests for PHP](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/)

Comment: Yes you can use CURL to simulate any HTTP request and it will also track cookies for you. The CURL PHP library is just a wrapper over http://curl.haxx.se/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other part of the answer lies here. You can achieve this with **`cURL`**.

Using **`cURL`** you can able to login to website. A sample example here gives you a kick-start.

```
<?php
$username="name@mail.com"; 
$password="mypassword"; 
$url="http://www.myremotesite.com/login.php"; 

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/), but usually *big* services offer an API interface to interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q="INSERT INTO `table`(`fname`, `lname`, `phone`, `zipcode`, `status`, `pregnant`, `month`, `day`, `year`, `ft`, `inch`, `lb`, `people`, `email`, `annual`, `recent`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `quotetype`, `unsubscribe`, `unsubscribe_type`) VALUES (
    '".$_POST['fname']."',
    '".$_POST['lname']."',
    '".$_POST['ph']."',
    '".$_POST['zip']."',
        'Accept',
    '".$_POST['gender']."',
    '".$_POST['mm']."',
    '".$_POST['dd']."',
    '".$_POST['yyyy']."',
    '5','8','80',
    '".$_POST['kids']."',
    '".$_POST['email']."',
    '".$_POST['income']."',
    '".$_POST['type']."',
    '".$_POST['address']."',
    '".$_POST['city']."',
    '".$_POST['state']."',
    'Lead','0','no')";
    $sql=mysql_query($q);
    if($sql)
    {echo "Lead Successfully submitted";}
    else
    {echo "Not Done";} 
    //Recive Data page like : get-data.php
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted this answer to the right question?

Comment: Yes this is a complete answer of this question.Because i was find answer from last 2 days. but still not get a complete answer.after that i find solution and post complete answer

Answer (score 0):

$handle = curl_init();

$url = "http://example.com/test.php";

// Array with the fields names and values.

$postData = array(

'firstName' => '',

'lastName'  => 'Gaga',

'submit'    => 'ok'
);

curl_setopt_array($handle,

array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,

```
 // Enable the post response.

CURLOPT_POST       => true,

// The data to transfer with the response.

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER     => true, ));
```

$data = curl_exec($handle);

curl_close($handle);

echo $data;

Answer (score -1):

```
$url="https://example.com/add_lead.php"; 

$postdata = "fname=".$fname."&lname=".$lname."&mm=".$mm."&dd=".$dd."&yyyy=".$yyyy."&email=".$email."&city=".$city."&state=".$state."&zip=".$zip."&address=".$address."&gender=".$lname."&ph=".$ph."&income=".$income."&type=".$type."&kids=".$kids; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

//Send Request Parameter Page like send-data.php