# Search On Website using php variable - DOM Parsing

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, scrapy

I want to search on website pragmatically using PHP like as we search on website manually, enter query on search box press search and result came out.

Suppose I want to search on this [website](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/) by products names or model number that are stored in my csv file.

if the products number or model number match with website data then result page should be displayed ..

I search on below question but not able to implement.

[Creating a 'robot' to fill form with some pages in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270335/creating-a-robot-to-fill-form-with-some-pages-in)

[Autofill a form of another website and send it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787872/autofill-a-form-of-another-website-and-send-it)

Please let me know how we can do this PHP ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a “crawler” for websites.

There are some things to consider first:

1. You code will never be generic. Each site has proper structure and you can not assume any thing (Example: craigslist “encode” emails with a simple method)
2. You need to select an objective (Emails ? Items information ? Links ?)
3. PHP is by far one of the worst languages to do that.

I’ll suggest using C# and the library called AgilityHtmlPack. It allows you to parse HTML pages as XML documents (So you can do XPath expressions and more to retrieve information).

It surely can be done in PHP, but I think it will take at least 10x time in php compared to c#.